# Change default copyright notice in Javadoc page footer

Tags: maven-javadoc-plugin

I am generating Javadoc pages for my project using the Maven Javadoc plugin, with mostly default settings.

I have noticed that each generated page has the following footer text:

> Copyright © 2020. All rights reserved.

How can I change this text to something of my choice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `bottom` element in the plugin config. Like this:

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-javadoc-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>3.2.0</version>
  <configuration>
    <bottom>
      Copyright © 2018–2020 The ACME Project. Licensed under GPL 3.0.
    </bottom>
  </configuration>
</plugin>
```

If you want to use HTML in your footer, you need to specify it as `CDATA`:

```
<![CDATA[Copyright © 2018–2020 The ACME Project. Licensed under <a href="https://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html" target="_blank">GPL 3.0</a>.]]>
```